# How do I get all the attributes of an XML element using Go?

Tags: go

I am trying to parse xml content along with all the attributes of an XML element  like this

```
type Node struct {
  XMLName xml.Name
  Attributes []xml.Attr `xml:",attr"`
  BodyElements string `xml:",innerxml"`
  Nodes   []Node `xml:",any"`
}

var xmldata = []byte("<div><div data-id=\"images/6C7161080\" data-imagesize=\"medium\" data-alignment=\"none\"></div></div>")

func walk(nodes []Node, f func(Node) bool) {
  for _, n := range nodes {
    if f(n) {
        walk(n.Nodes, f)
    }
  }
}


func main() {

  buf := bytes.NewBuffer(xmldata)
  dec := xml.NewDecoder(buf)

  var n Node
  err := dec.Decode(&n)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  walk([]Node{n}, func(n Node) bool {
    if n.XMLName.Local == "p" {
        fmt.Println(string(n.BodyElements))
    } else if n.XMLName.Local == "div"{
        fmt.Println(string(n.BodyElements))
        fmt.Println(len(n.Attributes))
    }
    return true
  })
}
```

But the value of len(n.Attributes) is always 0. What can I do to get all the attributes in the given element. NOTE: The attribute names are not constant as sometime the element can be a "div" tag or "img" tag or something else. So I can't use the attribute name as

```
DataId string `xml:"data-id,attr"`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that unmarshalling XML to your `struct Node` doesn't work. Your `BodyElements` captures the whole content of your root node and nothing is unmarshaled to your `Nodes`. (Btw: Adding a simple fmt.Printf would have revealed this.)

Why do you try to write your own XML unmarshalling/parsing code? You will fail.
Just use the Decoder and the `Token` method to parse your XML by hand, one token after each other, populating your tree manually. And: If your XML actually is HTML you might want to parse it with package html.